# Array json into array json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm a little new to JSON Syntax.
How can I extract the value of `listeners` from this `JSON` array?

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=31f2cd3c2530c87e110cc5212166d24c&artist=Britney%20Spears&track=If%20U%20Seek%20Amy&format=json

I've tried with `myvar.track.listeners` but it doesn't work. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

The code that I'm using to get that value is:

```
    function getInfo(artista, titolo) {
artista = artista.replace(" ","%20");
titolo = titolo.replace(" ","%20");
$.post("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=31f2cd3c2530c87e110cc5212166d24c&artist="+artista+"&track="+titolo+"&format=json", {}, function(data) {
    $("#listeners").html("<span class=\"span_listeners\">Ascoltatori: "+data.track.listeners+"</span>");
}, "json");
}
```

Comment: `track.listeners` is correct, but I'm fairly sure you can't name a variable `var`. Check your javascript console for errors. A little more context on what you tried would be helpful too.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to obtain the JSON?

Comment: @JasonP Ops, I didn't name the variabile `var`, that was just to explain what I was doing. However, I just wanted to get that value with jQuery.
@xaro Ok.

Comment: @Davide. Is there a particular reason you're doing a post? Check your error console, you're probably getting blocked by same origin restrictions. You'll probably need to use jsonp (if the service supports it)

Comment: @JasonP My error console says "[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data.track.listeners')"

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5L9Dd/. You probably have to test which properties `data` has in case you make a query which doesn't return any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save this JSON to a variable `response`, then using `response.track.listeners` you should have the value you want.

The JSON you posted is not an array. JSON arrays are delimited by `[...]`, as can be seen in the array `track.toptags.tag` in your document.

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_json = {"track":{"id":"243317.....};

console.log(my_json.track.listeners);
```

...should be OK. But if you named your JSON object "var" it won't work (javascript keyword to declare a variable).